# Podio ASP.NET Example App - Are the database scripts missing?

Tags: podio

Today I downloaded the Podio ASP.NET Example App (https://github.com/podio/asp-net-sample), as recommended in the *"Client Libraries: .NET - Podio API Documentation"* (https://developers.podio.com/clients/dotnet), and managed to get the solution up and running with a bit of jiggery-pokery. However, when I run the solution I get an exception around the expected **PodioAspnetSampleDb** database.

The solution references the connection-string `"server=WSA07;database=PodioAspnetSampleDb;user id=sa;password=pass"` in the web.config. Since this didn't connect, I created a local SQL database with the same name and altered the connection-string to point to this. When I run the solution again, it complains about missing tables.

Could it be that there is a database script or two that should be run to create a new database locally? If so, it would be great if these were included in the both the Git repository and the documentation.

Thanks,

Kaine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve this easily enough. So, if you're interested, I did the following:

1. Created a local DB called **PodioAspnetSampleDb**
2. Created a single table in the DB called **PodioOAuthData**
3. Added a primary key column called **UserId** of type **int**
4. Added a **varchar(max)** column called **OAuthJsonData**
5. Altered the **connection-string** in the **web.config** to point to my new DB

And that's it! Good luck with your project.

Kaine